# Can a Javascript Array or Object be overridden to be callable?

Tags: javascript, arrays, monkeypatching

I want to figure out if Array[] and Object[] can be replaced by Array() and Object(). Can a function prototype be stuck into arrays or objects prototype chain to make them callable. Basically I am looking for some thing like this:

```
// some magic with prototypes
????????????????

a = [1, 3, 4]
b = [1, 3, 4]

console.log(a[1]) // prints 3
console.log(b(1)) // prints 3

a[0] = -1
// same as
b(0, -1)

console.log(a[1], b(1)) // prints -1 -1
```

Thanks alot!

Comment: I think I have a solution for this, but I'm still doing research...

Comment: NO it cannot be done. Why do you want `b(0, -1)` ?

Comment: @ThomBlake I am. One cannot create an Array-like object that is callable. Without a proxy of course, using es:h proxies you can do pretty much anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't want to do this, especially in any browser. This doesn't have a lot of nice features of Array, including efficiency.  That said:

```
function ArrayFunction (arr) {
  var f = function s (p, v) {
    if (v !== undefined) {
      s[p] = v
    }
    return s[p]
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    f[i] = arr[i]
  }

  return f
}

var a = new ArrayFunction([1, 3, 4])
var b = new ArrayFunction([1, 3, 4])

b(1, 5)
a[1] //3
b[1] //5
```

I originally wanted to use prototypes, but objects don't inherit callableness from their prototypes.

**EDIT:** Fixed above to not use `arguments`.  This version does not allow you to set a value to `undefined`, but that's generally not considered a good practice anyway.

Comment: You should explain what you mean by making JavaScript engines 'very sad'. I think what you mean is that functions that use `arguments` are slower.

Comment: @JuanMendes Yeah, that and making the baby Jesus cry.

Comment: Wow this is some monstrosity!  Its getting close to what i was looking for.  I wonder if this new ArrayFunction can be made to be implicit when creating a new array or object?

Comment: [You broke `.length` and forgot to clone `Array.prototype` methods in](http://jsfiddle.net/LUYJJ/5/)

Comment: @Raynos I didn't forget - I thought it was bad enough already.  I wouldn't trust cloning the Array.prototype methods since it's not really an Array - if I was using this and wanted those methods, I'd write them myself.

Comment: @ThomBlake I'm just demonstration you can't make a callable array without using a Proxy

Comment: This is useful while creating mock objects. I created my own mock for jquery, for a limited behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Good question but the answer is no, because objects are not functions.

The closest you can get is this:

`Array.prototype.set = function(a,b) { this[a] = b; };`

Then you can do:

`b.set(0, -1);`

Comment: Yup, and I would add to that you cannot override the behavior of either a function invocation `()` or an indexed array access `[]` in JS.

Comment: well, functions are objects, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript does not support operator overloading like that.  I can't think of a way to have one variable support both [] and () access, but if you don't need [] access, you could try something like:

```
var weird_array = (function() {
    var data = [1,2,3];
    return function(idx, n) {
        if (arguments.length === 1)
            return data[idx];
        else if (arguments.length === 2)
            return (data[idx] = n);
    };   
})();
```

In this example, `weird_array` is not actually an array, so you cannot use []'s on it, but it is a function (wrapped around a data array).  You could then do:

```
weird_array();  // => undefined
weird_array(0); // => 1
weird_array(1); // => 2
weird_array(2); // => 3
weird_array(3); // => undefined
weird_array(1, 5); // => 5
weird_array(1); // => 5
```

Comment: Thanks!  How cool, you can build closures out of objects and objects out of closures, but staidly I need both the () and [] forms.